# react redux - global loader for multiple async requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async-await

On single page I have 4 separate components and one main component with this 4 components. I need to dispatch(showLoader()) once and hide global loader when async request in this 4 components ends. Now I tried to make dispatch(showCounterLoader()) which increments variable in state to 4, and on every completed async request i'm dispatching hideCounterLoader() with -1 value. If this value will be 0 i'm hiding global loader. This solution works but i'm looking for maybe better?

```
dispatch(showLoader()) -> counter: 4 -> showLoader: true
dispatch(showCounterLoader()) -> counter: 3
dispatch(showCounterLoader()) -> counter: 2
dispatch(showCounterLoader()) -> counter: 1
dispatch(showCounterLoader()) -> counter: 0 -> showLoader:false
```

Comment: If you know which are the first and last requests that get resolved then you can switch `showLoader` based on them. You don't have to maintain a `counter` state.

Comment: @Ramesh I don't know because every request is asynchronous

Comment: Can you add more code like when and where are you dispatching these actions

Comment: EDIT: https://pastebin.com/eDFeyrZa  loadPageData is called in componentDidMount on every components

Comment: Actually, if you aren't maintaining four different reducers but instead if you only have one reducer right now then your approach is fine. The only thing I would improve is I'll rename the `counter` to `pendingRequests` as it better conveys what it is being used for.

Comment: Actually every component has own store but they are combine in one. You're right with name, Thanks :)